# Entity Framework, select with "if exist" -like condition

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity

I'll try to explain my problem clearly, since it's quite complicated.

I've the following scheme on my DB with tables:

A(1)->(n)B(n)->(n)C(1)->(n)D(1)<-(n)E

Meaning that one element of A is related to many elements of B etc.
The direction of the arrow is about the foreign keys. B as an id_A , but A as not id_B etc.

My aim is to select "all the elements of A with at least one element of E following the condition "CONDITION".

I've tried a cascade of "where" and "any" with lines long as my arm but didn't find any success.

Is there any simple way to do this?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Could you please add some of your attempts at the where / any statements? In complex queries like you are looking to achieve it can sometime make life easier to think about the SQL you are expecting entity framework to generate and use that to think about how the query might look.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
from a in A
where a.Bs.Any(b => b.Cs.Any(c => c.Ds.Any(d => d.Es.Any(e => CONDITION(e)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, I've found a solution using a sql server view.

It is simple, needs 4 inner joins and 4 conditions.

Thanks again!